# Where did that useful multiline string watch window from Visual Studio 2010 go in newer versions?

Tags: visual-studio, watch

In Visual Studio 2010 if you had a very long string with multiple lines, you could hover over the variable and click on the magnifying glass icon:
[image]
This would bring up a little window called "Text-Schnellansicht" in german, so probably something like "Text quick watch" in english:
[image]
This way you could quickly understand the content of a complicated string variable.

In Visual Studio 2019 I can't find this window anywhere. There's no magnifying glass icon in the tooltip-thingie. Closest thing I could find was right-clicking on that, selecting "Copy value" and pasting it into notepad or some other editor.
[image]

So... is it just gone, along with all the other useful features that got removed throughout the years? Or was it just buried deep enough so that no one would find it?

**Edit:**

The epic tale of "How can we make our flagship IDE more painful to use?" continues:
Back in the good'ol days you could have this window for any variable you want:
[image]
Click on the hourglass, see what you got.

2019:
[image]
It **only** works for actual String variables. Because no other type could possibly have a string-representation that long, right?

Comment: Your edit is the real answer. The visualizer only shows for System.String, not other long DebuggerDisplay values. This is very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string visualizer is still there for me in VS 2019:

[image]

[image]

Documentation also suggests that it should be available https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/string-visualizer-dialog-box?view=vs-2019

Comment: What the hell? Now it's there for me too. Jesus christ, is it because the variable I tried to watch is actually a StringBuilder and not a String?..... Yes. Yes it is. Goddamnit, Visual Studio!